# Showing dependence of random variables

Tags: probability, random-variables, independence

I have two random variables X and Y and probabilities:

$P_X(-1) = P_X(1) = P_Y(-1) = P_Y(1) = \frac{2}{5} $ and $P_X(0) = P_Y(0) = \frac{1}{5} $

I have shown that $Cov(X, Y) = 0$, with $E(XY) = E(X) = E(Y) = 0$, now I must prove that they are not independents, but I don't know how to do it without knowing the joint probability distribution.

So by this [Covariance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Covariance), I know that:

$Cov(X,Y) = E(XY) - E(X)E(Y) $ and $$Cov(X,Y) = \frac{1}{nk}\sum_{i=1}^{n}\sum_{j=1}^{k}(x_i - E(X))(y_j - E(Y)) $$ for the discrete case, where $n = k = 3$, given that $X$ and $Y$ assume values -1, 0 and 1.

With the second equation I know that $Cov(X,Y) = 0$, then the first gives me $E(XY) = E(X)E(Y)$, but $E(X) = E(Y) = 0$, so $E(XY) = 0$.

Can anybody help?
Thanks

Comment: How did you show that they are uncorrelated without knowing the joint pmf? Do you have another source of information not shown here?

Comment: No, I just wrote $cov(X,Y) $ as defined here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Covariance on the section of Discrete Variables.

Comment: How did you compute $E(XY)$ without knowing the joint pmf?

Comment: Again, I used the information on the link above, so: $cov(X,Y) = E(XY) - E(X)E(Y)$.

Comment: Can you show me (us) how do you have computed $E(XY)$ ?

Comment: I edited the post.

Comment: In your calculation of the covariance you have assumed that they are independent. Then it is no surprise that the covariance is zero.

Comment: Covariance is $\mathsf {Cov}(X,Y) ~{= \mathop{\qquad\sum}\limits_{(x,y)\in\{-1,0,1\}^2} (x-\mathsf E(X))(y-\mathsf E(Y))\mathsf P(X=x,Y=y)\\= \mathop{\qquad\sum}\limits_{(x,y)\in\{-1,0,1\}^2} xy~\mathsf P(X=x,Y=y)}$  So... Without knowing the joint pmf you *cannot* calculate the covariance.

Comment: Note also that the formula for covarinance you have used is for *independent uniform distributions*, which is not compatible with the marginal distributions you had been given.

Answer (score 2):

**Outline:**

I have found a counterexample. In this example $Cov (X,Y)\neq 0$

$$\begin{array}{|c|c|c|c|c|}\hline &-1&0&1& \\ \hline -1&\frac1{10}& \frac1{10} & \frac2{10}& \frac4{10} \\ \hline 0&\frac1{10}& 0 & \frac1{10}& \frac2{10} \\ \hline 1&\frac2{10}& \frac1{10} & \frac1{10}& \frac4{10} \\ \hline &\frac4{10}& \frac2{10} & \frac4{10}& 1 \\ \hline \end{array}$$

$$Cov(X,Y)=\sum_{i=1}^3 \sum_{j=1}^3 x_i\cdot x_j\cdot f(x_i,x_j)-\left(\sum_{i=1}^3 x_i\cdot f(x_i)\right)\cdot \left(\sum_{i=j}^3 x_j\cdot f(x_j)\right) $$

$$=1\cdot \frac1{10}+0\cdot \frac1{10}-1\cdot \frac2{10}+0+0+0-1\cdot \frac2{10}+0\cdot \frac1{10}-0\cdot 0=-\frac3{10}$$

I think what the paragraph at wiki mean is if $f(x_i,y_i) = \frac{1}{nk} \ \forall \ i,j$ then you can use the formula.